# Changing ActiveCell's Font Colour and Background Colour

Tags: excel, rgb

Please could someone help me.  I have two functions in VBA for Excel.
  The one is to change the active cell's font colour and it works perfectly.  The second is to change the active cells background colour, and it refuses to work. 
 In stackoverflow there is another similar query and I am using that method yet this simply won't work.  What am I doing wrong?  I want to just reference 3 cells with numberic values from Excel to see what the colour is going to be on the fly.

**Change ActiveCell Font Colour** (WORKING)

```
Public Function FontColour(R, G, B)
ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(R, G, B)
End Function
```

**Change ActiveCell Colour** (NOT WORKING)

```
Public Function CellColour(R, G, B)
ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(R, G, B)
End Function
```

Comment: Make them BOTH **Subs**

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing ColorIndex and Color?

ColorIndex can be used with values 1-56 and has a set of predetermined colours, where Color allows you to use any colour, as specified by RGB values.

Try and update your function to

```
Public Function CellColour(R, G, B)
  ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(R, G, B)
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Sylvia  Thank you.  That is the most logical change to make, and I replaced my code with yours for that function, yet I am still getting a #VALUE error on my function's return in Excel which doesn't make any sense to me.  I tried Dim'ing the R, G and B as integers because I thought maybe the datatype is picking up wrong.  That did not work.  I then tried longs.  That also did not work.  So I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the word "Index", as in:

```
ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(R, G, B)
```

Also, your routines should be Subs, not Functions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  The reason why I am calling it as a function is because I want to use it in Excel as I would for eg. =SUM to reference 3 cells in my spreadsheet which contains a number representing Red, Green and Blue. Therefore a SUB would not work.

Comment: User Defined worksheet Functions are meant to return a value to the caller.  They are not meant to alter the worksheet... as in change a cell's formatting. You will continue to receive errors as long as you continue attempting changing the formatting of the range. Even if you could do such a thing, the point of UDFs is to affect the caller... not the active cell.